# Country-based Super User Access

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

I'm looking to provide super-user access to entities belonging to a specific country.

eg. Swedish SU can only admin Swedish entities, etc...

However, I'm new to django (taking over an old system) and I need a lifeline.

I'd like to be able to specify a relationship table.

I've already added a userprofile and with that I have a new field called super_user_country_link = models.ForeignKey(SuperUserToCountry, blank=True, null=True)

and then underneath a new class

```
class SuperUserToCountry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

I plan to run script then to add an entry for each superuser and give them a link to country 0 (ie, no country => total su access).
I can then remove these entries as I start to put country-specific entries in
So later I can call(using houses as an example):

```
if user.is_superuser:
    if user.get_profile().super_user_county_link.country == 0:
        #show house detail...
    elsif user.get_profile().super_user_county_link.country == 0
        #show house detail...
    else
        pass
```

So looking at it, this should mean that I can list multiple countries against a single user, right? Maybe I'm over-thinking it, but does this look correct?

I'm coming from a php background, so I'm just slighty dubious over how correct this is...

Comment: You should try and make your question more comprehensible.

Comment: The `if` and first `elsif` conditions in your second code snippet are the same. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong. It seems to me that you are trying to establish an many to many relationship between `UserProfile` and `Country`. If so the best way to go about it would be to use a [`ManyToManyField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). Something like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

You can leave it at that without requiring a separate model (`SuperUserToCountry`) as long as you are not storing any other information as part of this relationship. If in case you do plan to store other info, there is a [way for that too](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

The conditions `blank = True` and `null = True` are not needed here. If no countries are associated with an user profile then the countries will return an empty lost (i.e. `an_instance.countries.all()` will be empty).

When you start adding countries you can do something like this:

```
profile = User.get_profile()
denmark = Country.objects.get(name = 'Denmark')
russia  = Country.objects.get(name = 'Russia')

if denmark in profile.countries.all():
    print "Something is rotten in the state of Denmark"
elsif russia in profile.countries.all():
    print "In Soviet Russia, profiles have countries!"
```

The above conditions can most likely be expressed more precisely based on your specific need. Incidentally you'll add a country to an user's profile like this:

```
profile = User.get_profile()
denmark = Country.objects.get(name = 'Denmark')
profile.countries.add(denmark)
```